# How to write a inner join in Eloquent ORM in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have a tables named `buildings` and `flats`

**buildings table**

```
Building_Id | Building_Name | .......| Building_Owned_By | ....
```

**flats table**

```
Flat_Id | Flat_Name | ........| Fk_Building_Id | .....
```

and in My Models

**Building**

```
class Building extends Eloquent {
    protected $primaryKey = "Building_Id";
    protected $table = 'buildings';
    .......
    .......
    public function flat()
    {
        return  $this->hasMany('Flat', 'Fk_Building_Id', 'Building_Id');
    }
}
```

**Flat**

```
class Flat extends Eloquent {
    protected $primaryKey = "Flat_Id";
    protected $table = 'flats';
    .......
    .......
    public function building() {
        return $this->belongsTo('Building','Fk_Building_Id', 'Building_Id');
    }
}
```

and in my controller

```
$flats =  Flat::where('Fk_Building_Id', '=',$buildingid)
               ->where('Building_Owned_By', '=',Auth::user()->Login_Id)
               ->orderBy('Flat_Name')
               ->get(array('Flat_Id as flatId', 'Flat_Name as flatName'))
               ->toArray();
```

But it returns nothing.

How can we perform inner joins in Eloquent Orm (I dont want to use fluent query)?

**Update**

Thanks for @Creator for his valuable time and help. He helps me  a lot for finding this. The solution is we have to  use [whereHas](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#dynamic-properties) and we rewrite the code as

```
$flats =  Flat::whereHas('building', function($q){ 
                      $q->where('Building_Owned_By', '=',Auth::user()->Login_Id);
               })
               ->where('Fk_Building_Id', '=',$buildingid)
               ->orderBy('Flat_Name')
               ->get(array('Flat_Id as flatId', 'Flat_Name as flatName'))
               ->toArray();
```

Answer (score 4):

Do this :

```
class Building extends Eloquent {
protected $primaryKey = "Building_Id";
protected $table = 'buildings';
.......
.......
public function flat()
{
    return  $this->HasMany('Flat', 'Fk_Building_Id', 'Building_Id');
}
```

}

Query to get building with all flats:

```
   Building::with('flat')->(some_condition)->get();




class Flat extends Eloquent {
   protected $primaryKey = "Flat_Id";
    protected $table = 'flats';
   .......
   .......
  public function building() {
     return $this->HasOne('Building','Fk_Building_Id', 'Building_Id');
   }
}
```

Query to get flat with building info

```
      Flat::with('building')
          ->where('Building_Owned_By', '=',Auth::user()->Login_Id)         
          ->orderBy('Flat_Name')
          ->get(array('Flat_Id as flatId', 'Flat_Name as flatName'))
          ->toArray();
```

Comment: each flat have one buildingId and also may be two flats have same buildingID can occurs . I mean each buildin contains no of flats

Comment: Yup. it means one flat can have only one building. So hasOne should work. Have you tried above code?

Comment: yes ...I tried with the above code also . It returns null? How we  can  see  any sql errors or some  thing  like  that

Comment: You need to turn error_reporting on from php.ini. check answer again.

Comment: Simply do this for checking Flat::with('building')->get();

Comment: yes that is working....but if we add this line ->where('Building_Owned_By', '=',Auth::user()->Login_Id)  it is not working

Comment: With avoiding this line (where('Building_Owned_By', '=',Auth::user()->Login_Id) ), the result from foreach loop is this (with building null) Key=0and Value={"flatId":9,"flatName":"Dot Apartment5","building":null}

Comment: Thanks @Creator. for your valuable time and help. you help me  a  lot.I got  the answer that we  have  to use [whereHas](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#dynamic-properties) for conditions in realtions

Comment: @manuthalasseril thats allright man! Enjoy laravel!! Always do things step by step to avoid error. thats key to code. cheers

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Flat::with(array('building'=>function($query){
    $query->where('Building_Owned_By', '=',Auth::user()->Login_Id) 
 }))->where('Fk_Building_Id', '=',$buildingid)->orderBy('Flat_Name')
    ->get(array('Flat_Id as flatId', 'Flat_Name as flatName'))->toArray();
```