# how to defined Custom foreign key in Laravel's "belognsToMany" method?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

table MemberOwner:

> id | name | time

table Member:

> id | sex | age

talbe MemberOwner_Member:

> id | ownerid | memberid

and this is my relationship-defined code:

```
class MemberOwner extends Eloquent {

    public function members()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Member','MemberOwner_Member','?','?');
    }
}
```

look at the question mark above,how to fill with it?thank you,I've tried

> ownerid,memberid

and

> memberid,ownerid

but neither of them works,I need you help ,thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
class MemberOwner extends Eloquent {

public function members()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Member','MemberOwner_Member','foreign key','localkey');
  }
}
```

Here we are specifying this in MemberOwner model and for MemberOwner_Member table foreign key would be ownerid and if you want to specify local id then it would be id which is primary key there.
 Use this:

```
 class MemberOwner extends Eloquent {

   public function members()
   {
    return $this->belongsToMany('Member','MemberOwner_Member','ownerid');
  }
}
```

And this will work also if you want to specify local key.

```
 class MemberOwner extends Eloquent {

    public function members()
   {
      return $this->belongsToMany('Member','MemberOwner_Member','ownerid','id');
   }
}
```

Comment: return $this->belongsToMany('Member','MemberOwner_Member','ownerid','id');  the id is "MemberOwner.id"?  it doesn't work!

Comment: and without id? $this->belongsToMany('Member','MemberOwner_Member','ownerid');

Comment: I've fixed that,new question: how can I insert "many to many "relationship?  I have look up the doc ,it says "attach",but which I think it's just add the relation.but not the entity...

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21900679/how-to-write-a-inner-join-in-eloquent-orm-in-laravel/21901134#21901134